# Angular Jasmine SnackBar Testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

Could someone provide me a snippet of how to test whether a snackbar is called ? 
Do I need to set the Testbed for it and include in the imports ? 
Currently I am using a SnackBar that opens for an error message. I tried to spyOn this  method using,

```
spyOn(component.snackBar, 'open');
```

and then asserted it with,

```
expect(component.snackBar.open).toHaveBeenCalled();´
```

But I get an error message saying: 
**Error: spyOn : could not find an object to spy upon for open()
Usage: spyOn(object, methodName)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Jasmine.

Create mock: `mockSnackbar = jasmine.createSpyObj(['open']);`

Use the mock when creating the component: `component = new TheComponent(mockSnackbar);`

And check if the mock has been called: `expect(mockSnackbar.open).toHaveBeenCalled();`